# Why is my m.e.a.n. server so slow?

Tags: google-compute-engine, mean-stack

I started a m.e.a.n. server with google compute engine. It seems ok but should it be this slow? The server is http://130.211.66.116:3000/

Everything seems ok but the response time is like 30 seconds. Is it just that the example configuration has too little power and I must create a new VM with more dedicated power? I used the example from google.

How I start it:

```
$ gulp
Invoking gulp - development
[08:04:58] Using gulpfile ~/onacciweb/gulpfile.js
[08:04:58] Starting 'clean'...
[08:04:58] Finished 'clean' after 4.95 ms
[08:04:58] Starting 'default'...
[08:04:58] Starting 'coffee'...
[08:04:58] Finished 'coffee' after 7.29 ms
[08:04:58] Starting 'clean'...
[08:04:58] Starting 'less'...
[08:04:58] Starting 'csslint'...
[08:04:58] Starting 'env:development'...
[08:04:58] Finished 'env:development' after 33 μs
[08:04:58] Starting 'devServe'...
[08:04:58] Finished 'devServe' after 65 ms
[08:04:58] Starting 'watch'...
[08:05:04] Finished 'watch' after 5.31 s
[08:05:04] Finished 'clean' after 5.62 s
[08:05:04] [nodemon] v1.4.1
[08:05:04] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[08:05:04] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[08:05:04] [nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
debugger listening on port 5858
[08:05:05] 
[08:05:05] Finished 'less' after 6.53 s
[08:05:05] csslint: 3 files lint free
[08:05:05] Finished 'csslint' after 6.35 s
[08:05:05] Starting 'development'...
[08:05:05] Finished 'development' after 12 μs
loading docs for: /home/niklasro/onacciweb/packages/core/articles
Mean app started on port 3000 (development) cluster.worker.id: 0
[08:05:07] index.html reloaded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your issue is that livereload.js is timing out.  On that Click to Deploy, I believe there are some *post deployment* steps that must be completed for final configuration of the MEAN instance.  Did you successfully complete those?

Comment: I'm looking at the instructions and I can't see any post deployment steps. I'm going to do it all again to see if I'm missing something from my setup.